# How can a third-party site know your identity on other sites (e.g. Off-Facebook Activity)?

Tags: cookies, facebook, tracking

I'm a software engineer by trade, yet I am shocked and fascinated by something I learned just recently. For example, I found out Facebook has businesses and sites share information about my activity on their sites with Facebook. Many sites do this including ones I would not expect. Sidestepping all other types of moral, legal or social questions surrounding this, how do they even do it?

Even if I'm logged into Facebook on a given device or in a given tab, if I visit say foo.bar on another tab, and foo.bar has an agreement to share my activity with Facebook, and granting that Facebook probably never exposes my actual name, but only an account reference, how could they expose even that much on a different site? I'm sure there's not global browser state that any website can write to, right? Standards and implementations prevent that, right? Therefore they must find ways to skirt and circumvent that, right?

How has Facebook leaked or exposed my identity (or an account reference) to said third party site? I thought all such means of sharing information and communicating were (like cookies) were blocked off and quarantined by official web-standards. If I visit one site, say blue.com, is it able to store something so that every other site I visit can read what it has stored and know I visited it (if they share that info)? Or does Facebook get access to it's own cookies set when I was on Facebook.com, if the business websites I visit load a Facebook Iframe or call an XHR request to Facebook for a button or something insignificant, and that Iframe or XHR allows them to get the cookies they once planted on my device, which can also be viewed by the main site I went to visit (i.e. notblue.com) to do with as they please?

If so it's really the business site that's exposing me, by the infrastructure and willingness to do this and my beef should be with them. I'm sure it is done with numerous other sites besides FB and I just used them as an example, because that's how I discovered it, but is this how the technology works? Come to think of it, there's been a lot of internet magic I haven't been able to explain, like how google knows its me across domains like drive and YouTube and Gmail. I assume they use the same mechanism as Off-Facebook activity and I should learn how this works.

I don't mind reading very technical information to understand this- RFCs and such. It's really crazy how so much data can be traded that I didn't even think was possible. It seems that all that's required for two businesses to talk is an an agreement and an implementation, and then what you do on one will be known by other, without you even knowing. Is there a way to turn this off, and is this what the Brave Browser accomplishes? Maybe that's its raison d'etre.

Comment: This sounds like a question which would be way better suited for [Superuser.com](https://superuser.com/) than for this site. Don't forget to delete your question here *before* you post it there, for not creating a crosspost.

Answer (score 2):

"I'm sure there's not global browser state that any website can write to, right"

Yes and no. Say I own the domain "genericadverts.com". I goto various companies with websites and say "If you put my ads on your site I will give you money. Just add a script tag with [https://genericadverts.com/getAdverts"](https://genericadverts.com/getAdverts%22)

Now I get multiple websites to sign up to the deal. the script is loaded from the same domain on all the sites, so it can write and read the same cookie across all those pages. The JS has access to the DOM of the page it loads in and can communicate back home.

If there is no cookie I will generate a new one with a GUID. I will send the name of the site with whatever other info I collect back home with that GUID. I will show adverts based on that collected information, did you browse to sites that sell product X? do users of site Y fit a certain demographic etc etc

If you are facebook you can do the same thing with those little "share on facebook/youtube/whatever" buttons that people used to slap everywhere for free.